# Feature Importances for categorical features after one hot encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

We need to encode a categorical feature with multiple categories, the resulting one-hot encoded feature will have importance scores separately for each category. If we want to combine these importances into a single feature importance for the original categorical feature, can we simply add the importances for each one hot encoded feature.

For example, let's say we one hot encode a categorical feature called Department.

Resulting values

Department_0 : 0.03
Department_1 : 0.08
Department_2: 0.12

To combine these into a single feature importance for ‘Department’, can we sum up the values ?

Department : 0.03 + 0.08 + 0.12= 0.23.

Is there any drawback in this approach ? If yes, then what is the best approach ?

Answer (score 2):

When calling the attribute feature_importances_ on an sklearn estimator, you notice that the sum of all makes 100%.

Therefore I would say it makes sense to sum the importance when you regroup features together:

feature_importance(featureA & featureB) = feature_importance(featureA) + feature_importance(featureB)